# Was Lenny's dance scene inspired by James Bond movies?

Tags: x-men-cinematic-universe, legion

In [Legion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legion_(TV_series)) Season 1 Episode 6, there is this dance scene performed by Lenny ([Aubrey Plaza](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aubrey_Plaza)):

This is the [Goldeneye](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GoldenEye) one:

And [The spy who loved me](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Spy_Who_Loved_Me_(film)):

The **dance and the animations** look a lot like some of the bond movies.
The animation that has her body painted black or red with a different color background is **really** close to the bond movies.

#### **Was this scene (especially the animation) inspired by any bond movie's openning credits?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree the dance scene looks very much like the Bond dance sequences. During my previous research I read the script of Legion is so specifically created, every detail is in there for a reason.

According to The Hollywood Reporter's interview with Aubrey Plaza:

> The therapist sessions and the showdown with David aren't even Plaza's
>   only big swings of the episode. A quarter of the way through the hour,
>   Lennie breaks away from her office desk and embarks on a dance number
>   set to a Bassnectar remix of Nina Simone's "Feeling Good." Lennie's
>   silhouette dances across red and black backgrounds, before the
>   flesh-and-blood version of the character swings through hospital
>   rooms, shreds pillows to pieces, and eventually calmly resumes her
>   work. Plaza says there was "a very minimal description in the script
>   for that sequence," boiling down to a single sentence.
>
> "It went something like: 'Lennie dances with malevolent joy — a dance
>   of the wild things,'" she remembers. "It was something like that; I
>   don't want to quote Noah exactly there, because I'm not sure. But it
>   was a very descriptive sentence, and I just took that and ran with it.
>   I came up with a mini music video in the middle of the show. I knew
>   what the song was and I knew the sets I was going to be on, and I just
>   worked with a choreographer and tried to let loose."

So, it is possible that Aubrey Plaza took things into her control and made the scene something out of a Bond movie dancing sequence. But it is obvious that the scene is not taken from any Bond movie.

Here is the [source](https://www.google.com.tr/amp/www.hollywoodreporter.com/amp/live-feed/legion-aubrey-plaza-her-difficult-scene-986405).

Update: She didn't know it was going to be in James Bond-style.

> “I didn’t know how they were going to edit it,” she says. “I didn’t
>   know there was going to be a James Bond-style silhouette thing either.
>   I shot a bunch of sequences on the sets of David’s memories, and then
>   did a dance sequence where it was just me in a green room surrounded
>   by green screens on all sides. Our schedule was so insane, we had to
>   fit those sequences in when we could. It wasn’t ‘One day is the dance,
>   and then I don’t have to think about it anymore!’ It was a lingering
>   kind of thing.”

[Source](http://ethanalter.tumblr.com/post/161776420982/emmys-legion-star-aubrey-plaza-on-just-trying) from Walt's comment.

Comment: I know the dance itself is not taken from the bond movies, but what about the animation? The body black or red on a different color background. That looks a lot like the bond movies.

Comment: @GustavoGabriel FWIW, [Plaza did call it 'Bond-style'](http://ethanalter.tumblr.com/post/161776420982/emmys-legion-star-aubrey-plaza-on-just-trying).

Answer (score 2):

Actually there are A LOT of 60's & 70's British period film influences in Legion, as Noah Hawley had mentioned in early interviews -- and no doubt some of it is very James Bond inspired (Oliver Bird)---But there are other film influences also from Stephen King (*It, The Shinning, Pet Sematary*) to Kubric (*Clockwork Orange*) or even Hitchcock (*The Birds* = Melanie Bird) or Jules Verne (*2,000 Leagues, Voyages Extraordinaries*) with the idea being that *Legion's* reality/universe is somewhat timeless.

The one dance scene in which Lenny "trashes" through David's memory is also in an episode that also has a **flash**back from Ptonomy's childhood, which is 30's-esque in aesthetic, but has a World War vibe as well, with the way the radio is used in the scene. However, the song on the radio is *99 Red Luftballoons* (an anti-war protest song) from the band Nena, which was a hit and released in 1983----IMO I believe the dancing style of Lenny is a parody to ***Flash Dance***, a 1983 film. Two songs from the film's soundtrack come to mind that would fit this scene (and character) perfectly, *Imagination* and *Maniac*.

Links to Interviews with Some Influences or Easter Eggs Sited:

Wikipedia (British Films, Alice in Wonderland, Eternal Sunshine of the Spotless Mind, David Lynch) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legion_(TV_series)

Possible Horror Film Allusions:
https://www.nytimes.com/2017/03/29/watching/legion-finale-horror-movies.html?mcubz=0

Comment: The following Interview from Deadline talks about it some of it generally--it specifically mentions Clockwork Orange.

Everything else is speculation based on my own film/viewing experience recognizing similar colors, characterizations, and allusions.

Fargo's infuence and others:

http://deadline.com/2017/06/legion-fargo-dana-gonzales-cinematography-emmys-interview-news-1202085351/

Twin Peeks Influence:

Comment: Twin Peaks Influence:
https://www.tvinsider.com/347321/noah-hawley-guest-column-fargo-legion-twin-peaks-david-lynch/

Comment: Twin Peaks Influence:
https://www.tvinsider.com/347321/noah-hawley-guest-column-fargo-legion-twin-peaks-david-lynch/

Movie References:
https://www.thrillist.com/entertainment/nation/legion-fx-season-1-easter-eggs-movie-references

Comment: I was trying to give you many links to read about a lot of different influences either Hawley/Gonzales mentioned or others have recognized, but there's only so much space--I apologize for all of the edits.

Comment: Wikipedia also sites: British Films, David Lynch, Alice in Wonderland, Eternal Sunshine of Spotless Mind (concept): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legion_(TV_series)

Comment: Oh I see, sorry I will add them to my post. Sorry again. misunderstood.